# show/hide div when user inputs text into text area?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle a div so it shows and hides when a user enters text into textarea.
i am using the below code and its not working for me, can anyone please show me why? thanks

html:

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cname").keyup(function() {
        if ($("#cname").val() > 8) {
             $('#cname2').toggle("slow");
        }
   });
});
</script>

</head>

<form>

<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="field">
<div id="cname2"></div>
</form>
```

css:

```
#cname2{
width:30px;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-13px;
margin-left:400px;
background-image: url('tick.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
display:none;

}
```

so apparently my above code doesnt work in IE 9, but i should be able to achieve what i am trying to do by using this code, but can someone please show me where i place my div ID/how i adapt it to work for me?

```
var activeElement = null;
var activeElementValue = null;

// On focus, start watching the element
document.addEventListener("focusin", function(e) {
    var target = e.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeName !== "INPUT") return;

    // Store a reference to the focused element and its current value
    activeElement = target;
    activeElementValue = target.value;

    // Listen to the propertychange event
    activeElement.attachEvent("onpropertychange", handlePropertyChange);

    // Override .value to track changes from JavaScript
    var valueProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
            HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
    Object.defineProperty(activeElement, {
        get: function() { return valueProp.get.call(this); },
        set: function(val) {
            activeElementValue = val;
            valueProp.set.call(this, val);
        }
    });
});

// And on blur, stop watching
document.addEventListener("focusout", function(e) {
    if (!activeElement) return;

    // Stop listening to propertychange and restore the original .value prop
    activeElement.detachEvent("onpropertychange", handlePropertyChange);
    delete activeElement.value;

    activeElement = null;
    activeElementValue = null;
});

function handlePropertyChange(e) {
    if (e.propertyName === "value" &&
            activeElementValue !== activeElement.value) {
        activeElementValue = activeElement.value;
        // Fire textchange event on activeElement
    }
};
```

Comment: working `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/SG8SQ/

Comment: check your jsfiddle as when i preview it it doesnt hide the div and its always on show

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/THkqE/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cname").on('input', function() {
       $('#cname2')[this.value.length > 8 ? 'hide' : 'show']('slow');
   });
});
```

Here I assumed that in `cname2` container there's some warning message, that has to be shown if *length* of text input is 8 or less characters. Note also that I've used `oninput` handler, not `keyup`: as it allows me to process mouse-driven cut-and-paste as well as direct input. The only drawback is that IE8 doesn't support this event (and IE9 support for it is rather buggy, as handler is not fired when character is *removed* from text input).

Comment: hey this is not working for me either, i feel i should mention im using IE 9 i dont know if this is the cause of my probelm

Comment: Sigh... yes, that's a problem. Still, there's a [shim](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html) for both IE9 and IE8. Of course, you can just change it to process `keyup` - but then it won't process mouse events.

Comment: would u please be able to show me how i can adapt the code to work in IE then please

Comment: Just replace `input` with `keyup`.

Comment: Check the console, are there any errors? I have no means to test it with IE9, but `keyup` IS supported by this browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#cname").keyup(function() {
            if ($("#cname").val().length > 8) {
                $('#cname2').show();
            } else {
                $('#cname2').hide();
            }
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Javascript function

```
var z = document.getElementById('cname');

z.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('cname2').innerHTML = z.value;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='cname' class='field' id='cname'>

    <div class='cname2' id='cname2'></div>
```

Checkout here: http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/Q9LPv/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cname").keyup(function() {
       if ($("#cname").val().length > 8) {
             $('#cname2').toggle("slow");
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: `toggle` is not used to togle css classes. Description from the jqeury site: Display or hide the matched elements.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

Comment: My bad, I mixed it with the .toggleClass() method :-|

Comment: Yes. `toggle()` and `slideToggle` toggle html elements, `toggleClass` toggles classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#cname").keyup(function() {
            if ($("#cname").val() > 8) {
                 $('#cname2').fadeIn("slow");
            }
           else
           {
                 $('#cname2').fadeOut("slow");
           }
       });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5EjP7/2/

I hope that helps

Comment: apparently this doesnt work in IE 9, do u know how i could get this to work in IE 9 at all please

Comment: Try to remove the "display:none;" from your CSS and hide the element on document.ready: updated my Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5EjP7/4/)

Comment: Your demo isn't working. `$("#cname").val()` returns string and you cannot compare strings and numbers.

Comment: @user3132718 It is working for me, but it's possible to parse the string to a number with parseInt()